# PL/SQL Autoregressive forecasting

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, forecasting, arima

Forgive me in advance as I'm not particularly good at at PL/SQL (or forecasting for that matter).

I was hoping someone might be able to help me with a forecasting problem / methodology in PL/SQL.

For this particular forecast lets say we need to produce 4 weeks(from today/a given date) of forecasted values for each product line from each production facility.

The difficulty I am facing is that my only means of deployment is an Oracle database package/stored procedure.

I am quite comfortable with the use of [ARIMA models (and VARIMA variants)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive%E2%80%93moving-average_model) in R, and would like to use something similar (best-case scenario develop something similar to an auto.arima method) but am constrained by my knowledge of PL/SQL

Here is a dummy table (populated with dummy data):

```
create table production_data
(
    product_id number,
    facility_id number,
    week_in_year number,
    prod_year number,
    units number
);

insert into production_data
select 1, 1, 1, 2019, 679862 from dual union all
select 1, 2, 1, 2019, 512345 from dual union all
select 1, 2, 2, 2019, 640000 from dual union all
select 2, 1, 1, 2019, 680000 from dual union all
select 2, 2, 1, 2019, 700000 from dual union all
select 2, 2, 2, 2019, 705365 from dual;
```

And here's what I have got so far (not much):

```
 --Ordinary least squares forecast for each product for each facility.
select
    product_id,
    facility_id,
    prod_year,
    max(week_in_year) + 1 forecast_end,
    -- y = mx+b
    regr_slope(units, prod_year)
        * (max(week_in_year) + 1)
        + regr_intercept(units, prod_year) forecasted_units
from production_data
group by 
    product_id,
    facility_id,
    prod_year
UNION ALL 
select
    product_id,
    facility_id,
    prod_year,
    max(week_in_year) + 2 forecast_end,
    -- y = mx+b
    regr_slope(units, prod_year)
        * (max(week_in_year) + 2)
        + regr_intercept(units, prod_year) forecasted_units
from production_data
group by 
    product_id,
    facility_id,
    prod_year
UNION ALL 
select
    product_id,
    facility_id,
    prod_year,
    max(week_in_year) + 3 forecast_end,
    -- y = mx+b
    regr_slope(units, prod_year)
        * (max(week_in_year) + 3)
        + regr_intercept(units, prod_year) forecasted_units
from production_data
group by 
    product_id,
    facility_id,
    prod_year
UNION ALL 
select
    product_id,
    facility_id,
    prod_year,
    max(week_in_year) + 4 forecast_end,
    -- y = mx+b
    regr_slope(units, prod_year)
        * (max(week_in_year) + 4)
        + regr_intercept(units, prod_year) forecasted_units
from production_data
group by 
    product_id,
    facility_id,
    prod_year;
```

Comment: @APC thank you for the edit, are you aware of any ways to generate auto.arima() style models in SQL or PL/SQL ?

Answer (score 2):

Cross joining the original table with dual table containing

`select from dual connect by level <= 4 * 7`

syntax which generates rows for the next four weeks starting from the current day :

```
select distinct 
       product_id,
       facility_id,
       prod_year,
       max(w.week_in_year) forecast_end,
       regr_slope(units, prod_year)
        * (max(w.week_in_year))
        + regr_intercept(units, prod_year) forecasted_units
 from production_data
cross join 
      (
       select to_char(sysdate+level-1,'iw') as week_in_year, level - 1 as lvl
         from dual
      connect by level <= 4 * 7
      ) w
group by product_id, facility_id, prod_year, lvl
order by forecast_end
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Barbaros (+1) but I was hoping to generate a VARIMA forecast. Is this possible?

Comment: hello @hello_friend :) you're welcome. I don't know about (v)arima but row generating mechanism may work like this.